# How do I fix " Cannot implicitly convert convert type 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' "?

Tags: c#

I've been having this problem and could not figure out how to fix it. I'm making a 2D game and need a rotating and shrinking hexagon.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hexagon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb; 
    public float shrinkSpeed = 3f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.rotation = Random.Range(0f, 360f);
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale -= Vector3.one * shrinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (transform.localScale.x <= .05f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I new to programming and I need help with this.

Comment: It is an issue with the rotation. See following for solution : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html

Comment: It sounds like @jdweng may have you covered, but as a general note: It would be useful to note what line you're getting the exception on.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ob : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody rb;

```
public float shrinkspeed = 4f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Quaternion randYRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Random.Range(0, 360), 0);
    transform.rotation = randYRotation;
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one *10f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.localScale -= Vector3.one * shrinkspeed * Time.deltaTime;
    
    if (transform.localScale.x <= .05f) 
    {
      Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}